# PHP - variable in constructor is empty in other functions of the class

Tags: php, function, oop, constructor, this

I am trying to access an associative array $foo from a function inside the class. When I log the contents from another function it is empty. I am really unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
class Item {
    function __construct($x = 1) {
        $y = do_something($x);
        
        $foo = [
            'id' => $y['anotherID'],
            'name' => $y['name']
        ];
    }

    function insertData($data) {
        $variable = $this->foo['id'];
        // if I print $this->foo['id'] I get no output
    }
}
```

I have also tried another recommendation of using self::$foo but got all sorts of errors about private and static?

Comment: You need to assign to `$this->foo`. Otherwise it's just an ordinary local variable, not a property.

Comment: @Barmar for some reason I cannot add your comment as a solution?

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer. I consider this to be trivial, like a typo, not worth an answer.

Comment: It's something you can easily learn about in examples and the documentation already, so it's unlikely to be worth an answer. Or at best, someone already asked the same thing in the past, so a keen searcher may dig up a duplicate at some point, and close the question as being a copy of that.

Comment: Please share more details. What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is `do_something` relevant for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $this->foo = [] instead of $foo = []. It makes it a property of the class.